# cURL and Requests not behaving the same (cURL gives JSON body, Requests just gives response code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm writing a script to pull metrics from a local Pyspark server.  In one part of my code, `requests` works perfectly fine; it returns the JSON data I want.  However, in another portion of the script `requests` (more specifically, `req.json`) just returns

`<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>` instead of actual JSON data (same with `req.json()`).

The URL that the request is being sent to you is 
`http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/local-1562033649191/executors/driver/threads`

That's what the line of code `req = re.get(URL)` is hitting and that's the URL I tested with cURL in the command line.  Different results.

I've checked that `req.url` matches the url that is being cURL'ed.

Edit: relevant code:

```
    # collect JSON from each given executor by the executor's respective URL
    for url in appExecutorIDURLs:
        req = re.get(url)
        print(req.json)
```

`appExecutorIDURLs` currently returns a one-element list:

`['http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/local-1562033649191/executors/driver/threads']`

Anyone have any insights on this?

Comment: found this the other day: 
https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @Richard I appreciate the response.  However, that didn't help as the `requests` code that was generated in that tool is the same as the code I have.

Comment: Provide the relevant parts of your script here. The "bound method" error you received is because you attempted to access a function instead of calling it. I'm interested to see why req.json() would result in the same output. There is likely a syntax related error in the script, which is why providing it would be useful.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner added relevant code to post, thanks.

Comment: what's the output of `print(req.text)`?

Comment: @Richard I should've included that.  That is the correct data as well.  Just `req.json` isn't.  Weird stuff.
Edit:  same with `req.content`

Comment: I suspect the issue is caused from the serverside endpoint you are calling. This issue is caused during `return response.json` instead of `return response.json()`

Comment: @Richard Not sure I understand.  The `.json` and `.json()` responses are the same.  They both only return the `<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>` response.  The "serverside endpoint" is a Spark server endpoint on `localhost` that works perfectly fine with cURL.  

How can I look further into this?

Comment: it's not as simple as `print(req.json())` ??  you don't have the brackets after .json

Comment: @Richard As I've mentioned, I've done both.  Same result.

Comment: Something isn't right here. First, you should definitely be using req.json() instead of req.json, as it is a method that should be called and not an element to be accessed. The error you receive matches the use of the code. Now, for req.json() to return a message stating "bound method..." doesn't really make since. Perhaps try help(req.json()) to see what Type it actually is, or use iPython for code completion suggestions. The message from req.json() really should be different. Perhaps try constructing a reproducible example? Also, when you print(req.text) does everything look correct?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add parentheses when you called `req.json()`? `req.json` asks for an attribute of the requests object, it doesn't call the `json()` method.

Alternatively, you can view the response body with

```
response = requests.get('url', ...)
response.content
```

Although this doesn't convert the response body to a dictionary by itself.

Hope this helps!